# Webpack DevServer host 0.0.0.0 not working on Windows

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

The following [Webpack dev server](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/) configuration works without errors on macos system:

```
module.exports = {

    // [...]

    devServer: {
        host: 0.0.0.0,
        port: 8080,
        contentBase: "/dist",
        hot: true,
        inline: true,
        watchOptions: {
            poll: true
        }
    },

    // [...]

}
```

I can access the web app from mobile device connected to the same network and using the local ip of the machine (192.168.1.65:8080).

The same configuration does not work on Windows, it seems it can't open 0.0.0.0 on the browser. But using any other ip other than 0.0.0.0 does not let access from mobile devices. Does anyone know how to fix this issue on Windows?

Comment: visit http://localhost:8080/ or 127.0.0.1:8080 instead of 0.0.0.0

Comment: yes I know that opening localhost or 127.0.0.1 works, but I was asking a fix to resolve 0.0.0.0 on windows

Comment: 0.0.0.0 is a non-routable meta-address used to designate an invalid, unknown, or non-applicable target (a ‘no particular address’ place holder).

Comment: Point `0.0.0.0` to '127.0.0.1` in the host file.. you can find the host file in the following location `C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts`

Comment: @Nour Yes I was thinking on that one! thanks

Comment: @revy you are welcome.

Comment: @revy Did it work to add the entry in the hosts file? Or have you found a good workaround?

Comment: "0.0.0.0" is a valid address for binding (hence its use in your config above), but it is _not_ a valid host address. if you have software that shows you a URL containing the host "0.0.0.0", then that software has a bug.

Answer (score -3):

0.0.0.0 is a [non-routable meta-address](https://superuser.com/questions/949428/whats-the-difference-between-127-0-0-1-and-0-0-0-0) used to designate an invalid, unknown, or non-applicable target (a ‘no particular address’ place holder).